# Wordpress blog with a custom made theme hosted on heroku

Tags: uploads

I have been trying to host a wordpress site on heroku. I have accomplished this by using a few git repositorie Heroku-Wordpress that has the quick deploy to Heroku button, it installs correctly my problem now is I built a custom wordpress theme and cannot upload it to wordpress using the add theme button is the wordpress dashboard. This is a git repository with my wordpress theme:

https://github.com/natashanodine/blog-set

It works when I upload to a regular hosting via ftp but I cannot get it to upload thru the dashboard weather it is hosted on heroku or on a regular hosting.

I need it to be upload to heroku so I need to figure out why I cannot upload the new theme using the add theme button in the dashboard

Comment: To upload the theme has to be zipped... ..so `blog-set.zip`... ...are you doing that?  Failing that, a lot of these 'push button' set-ups like Bitnami on AWS have hardened security/permissions sets, so that could also be your issue.  I've never invested the time to resolve it.  Sorry.

Comment: Yes I have zipped it. @TonyDjukic